# Nginx pass subdirectory as base url to Kohana

Tags: nginx, configuration, kohana

Having set up multiple Kohana applications on Nginx, I need to adjust the "base url" parameter for each application. Before when I was using Apache with `.htaccess` this was easy (`RewriteBase`) but in Nginx I have found the following solution:

```
location /sites/site1/ {
    try_files $uri /sites/site1/index.php?$args;
}

location /sites/site2/ {
    try_files $uri /sites/site2/index.php?$args;
}

...etc...
```

Now, since I would like to add many more applications, I'd rather have a single `location` block passing the Kohana application to the correct path. I've tried something like this (**this won't work for me**):

```
location /sites/([a-z0-9\-]+)/ {
    try_files $uri /sites/$1/index.php?$args;
}
```

As you may see, I'm not a regex expert, but I want to pass any existing subdirectory with names containing alphanumerical characters and dash to the corresponding base path. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need a prefix for `location` to do regex matching.  Try this:

```
location ~* ^/sites/([a-z0-9\-]+)/ {
    try_files $uri /sites/$1/index.php?$args;
}
```